# Z3 strategy for solving system with conditional integer additions

Tags: z3

I'm using Z3 to solve a system that consists of Boolean constraints on variables `Vi` as well as a constraint of the following form:

```
L < If(V0, T0, F0) + If(V1, T1, F1) + ... + If(Vn, Tn, Fn) <= H
```

where `L`, `H`, and the `Ti` and `Fi` are integer constants.

Although all the variables are Boolean, I found that the QF_LIA solver was somewhat faster than the generic one, so I'm using the former. My assumption was that Z3 was handling the constraint above by introducing new variables and clauses to implement adders in the obvious way. However, doing that conversion myself (using MiniSat+) and passing the result to a SAT solver takes an order of magnitude longer than Z3 does. Thus, I'm wondering what strategy Z3 uses to solve systems of the type described above - is it something other than the conversion using adders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Z3 uses a reduction to SAT to solve this kind of problem. If you are using the shell, you can provide the option `-v:10` (verbosity messages). Z3 will display several messages describing what it is doing.  For the kind of problem you described, Z3 will probably display verbose messages of the form:

```
(lia2pb :num-exprs 9 :num-asts 185 ...)
(pb2bv :num-exprs 9 :num-asts 185 ...)
```

`lia2pb` means that Z3 is converting a linear integer arithmetic problem into a pseudo boolean constraint problem. And `pb2bv` means that it is reducing the problem to bit-vector arithmetic.

The `lia2pb` transformation is implemented in the file:
http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/tactic/arith/lia2pb_tactic.cpp

and `pb2bv` transformation is implemented in the file:
http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/tactic/arith/pb2bv_tactic.cpp

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. With the verbose option Z3 did indeed display messages indicating that `lia2pb` and `pb2bv` were invoked, but when I attempted to call these manually in my SMT2 file, I got an error saying "goal is in a fragment unsupported by pb2bv". I turned on tracing with my original file and found that in fact Z3 wasn't using pb2bv: that tactic aborted with the message "Not pseudo-Boolean: (ite v118 (- 373266501405000) (- 653847452060000))". No subsequent messages in the verbose output mention tactics. So what reduction to SAT is being used?

Comment: `pb2bv` does not support arbitrary expressions. Z3 usually preprocess the input using other tactics before invoking `lia2pb` and `pb2bv`. You can find the precise sequence of tactics in the file https://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/tactic/smtlogics/qflia_tactic.cpp

Comment: The tactic `preamble_st` (created in the file above) contains the basic preprocessing used by Z3 for linear integer arithmetic problems. It will eliminate several constructs that are not supported by `pb2bv`.

Comment: When I tried using `pb2bv` manually I did use the tactics from qflia_tactic.cpp, including those in `preamble_st` (although I did get an error because `pb2bv` didn't recognize the option `:ite-extra` used in `mk_pb_tactic`, so I had to remove that option; I'm not sure what that means). But regardless, the "Not pseudo-Boolean..." message I got was when I didn't specify any tactics: I just specified the logic as QF_LIA, asserted my constraints, and called `check-sat`. So I think this means `pb2bv` was failing even with the preprocessing applied, and another tactic was used instead.

Comment: My bad, you are right, Z3 tries to use `pb2bv` in your example, but it fails. The `:ite-extra` option is defined in the file `src/sat/tactic/goal2sat.cpp`. It is not relevant since `pb2bv` fails. If it had succeeded, then this option would affect how `if-then-else` formulas are encoded as clauses.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. If I understand the code correctly, since my problem is bounded Z3 next invokes the general SMT solver, with an option to use no cuts. Is that right? If so I guess I'll be looking into how that solver works, since I'm curious how it is faster than conversion to a PB and then to a SAT problem (which is what I was doing before with some ad-hoc code to generate the PB problem, and then MiniSat+ to convert that to SAT).